# ng-container inside a loop not repeated

Tags: angular

for the following app
the "injected content" is displayed in the latest child component only, instead of being displayed in all child components

the parent component calls the child component three times, each time it injects content that is received from AppComponent.

[image]

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-npebzq)

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `child<br /><ng-content select="[slot]"></ng-content><hr />`,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class ChildComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <child *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3]">
     <ng-content slot select="[slot]"></ng-content>
    </child>
`,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ChildComponent],
})
export class ParentComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ParentComponent],
  template: `
    <parent>
      <ng-container slot>injected content</ng-container>
    </parent>`,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Comment: So ... Is there a question ?

Comment: Try to replace `<ng-container slot>injected content</ng-container>` with `<span slot>injected content</span>`, it might not work because `ng-container` and its attributes are not rendered (only it's inner content)

Comment: it is an issue, and I need a solution for it

Comment: thanks @Shaha for ur suggestion, unfortunately the same result

Comment: `<ng-content>` can only be projected once. If you need to render it multiple times, you NEED to [render templates](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/datatable/src/datatable/datatable.component.html#L16)

Answer (score 3):

You can't with `ng-content`, instead use `ng-template` and `ng-contatiner`:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
  child<br />
    <ng-content select="[slot]"></ng-content>
  <hr />
  `,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class ChildComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <child *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3]">
      <ng-container slot [ngTemplateOutlet]="tpl"></ng-container>        
    </child>
`,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ChildComponent],
})
export class ParentComponent {
  @Input() tpl!: TemplateRef<any>;

}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ParentComponent, ChildComponent],
  template: `
    <parent [tpl]="content">
      <div slot>injected content</div>
    </parent>

    <ng-template #content>
      <div slot>injected content</div>
    </ng-template>
    
    `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

In the main component (in this case `app`), send the content you want to repeat as an input of type TemplateRef:

```
<parent [tpl]="content">
      <div slot>injected content</div>
</parent>

<ng-template #content>
      <div slot>injected content</div>
</ng-template>
```

Then, on your `parent` componentt (wher you iterate with `*ngFor`), recive that content and use itt within a `ng-container`:

```
export class ParentComponent {
  @Input() tpl!: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

and

```
<child *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3]">
      <ng-container slot [ngTemplateOutlet]="tpl"></ng-container>        
</child>
```

Also, you can add de `slot` atribute to the container, for filtering in the child:

```
child<br />
    <ng-content select="[slot]"></ng-content>
<hr />
```

[image]

Comment: great suggestion, but the same result [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-npebzq)

Comment: It works for me [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hdkqwd?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Additionally, I always write a directive which injects the `TemplateRef` and component, and sets the template on the component. It makes the code more elegant. [Example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/datatable/src/row-template/row-template.directive.ts) / [usage](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/advanced/datatables/datatables.component.html#L13)